# Reseting VBA Datepicker Property to visible

Tags: excel, vba, datepicker, visibility

I'm facing a unusual problem here in my excel VBA userform.

Here, I have a Checkbox which when equal to true(ie, when checked) unhide a already hidden datepicker and it's label.

I'm hiding the label and the datepicker in the `userform_initialize` event using `label1.visible = false` & `dtpicker2.visible = false`. Then when the user clicks on the checkbox (in the `checkbox1_change` event) I'm turning the visibility of the label and datepicker back to *`true`*.

But, when doing so I'm able to see the label but not the datepicker.

**Note:-**

> 1) The Datepicker and it's label successfully hidden using the *`.visible`* function
>
> 2) When trying to set the *`.visible`* function back to ***true*** ONLY label comes back the datepicker still remains hidden
>
> 3) I'm using the COMCT2.cab file for the datepicker

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refresh the DateTime Picker:

`dtpicker2.Visible = True
dtpicker2.Refresh`